# Spheres facing to camera

Tags: animation, constraints

I need those spheres facing to camera so I can see the letters all the time. I guess I need to use constraints but not sure how (I'm a newbie, yes)

EDIT: I know Damped track do it but I need it in all the axys. I tried to add a Damped track to x, y and z but it doesn't work

Thanks[image]

Comment: It should work with Damped Track, you can try Track To but it is a bit the same, maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: you can try a track to constraint added to the balls targeted to the camera

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To avoid fiddling with geometry in the scenes themselves, you could use a shader, essentially treating your letters as matcaps.

Shoot 'spherical' letters: (mine is white emissive-material text, simple subdivided, shrink-wrapped to a non-rendered sphere,shot on transparent film.) Of course, you could shoot them flat if you preferred that look)

[image]

Then that component of your texture can be mapped, like a matcap, as follows:

[image]

As you can see, it's like @batFINGER's solution: the texture is parallel to the camera's Z, rather than pointing *at* it, but the effect is quite pleasing, and actually functional in crowded scenes:

[image]

Comment: Oops: that's a mask. The Image texture node should be set to 'Non-Color'

Comment: Man... no... wanted to say Mr Bestt... I've searched for that... but failed. Thanks, this is a great answer.

Comment: @lemon Luck. My head's spinning with another vector-space problem, atm.... and I haven't worked out _why_ the texture splays at the edges of the frame >:(

Comment: Again you push me to some studies... but that will be for tomorrow, I hope.

Comment: More elegant that I want to do. Thanks!

Comment: @lemon  got it.  Camera Space is orthogonal, no perspective transform, and the conversion from World, even when using 'Point', converts from World  orientation, but puts  0 at the Object origin.

Comment: Very nice solution - it's always good to see that Vector Transform node put to good use. Does the image actually need to be shot as 'spherical' - wouldn't the transform from the surface normal not be producing a similar (but less pronounced) bending anyway?

Comment: @Rich, as far as I can see, yes. The Normal _direction_ is interpreted as a _location_ in camera space, but then inversely interpreted by the surface of the sphere in the scene? (er.. how can I translate that into sensible English? I'm sure you can express that more cleanly) . Tests with grids confirm, I think.

Comment: It's certainly hard to wrap head around the different spaces and how it's going to bend - and I'm not sure I could express it any clearer either... it's complicated :-D However it's working, I think it's working really well and I like the way they bend nearer the edges of the frame too.

Comment: Wanted to try a little improvement. The case you shift the target instead of rotating around it and make the texture rotate to the camera. Though, I don't explain the values (factors) needed once the angles are obtained (@RichSedman, in case you're interested). https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/qdnaAZOy/

Comment: @lemon Thanks!.. You've got me hard at work, playing. _So. Many. Gotchas!_ [Here's a version](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ePoGoLBD/) which uses the cross-product between (the Camera > Sphere vector) , and (0,0,1) all in camera space, to get an axis of rotation perpendicular to both. Then uses the dot-product between those vectors to get the angle around it. To see the effect, play with the 'Amplify Angle' node. 0 is the uncorrected state.

Comment: @RobinBetts, much more clean and clear than mine (still don't get why I needed such values, though)... So... next step: get ride of distortions on poles and make it work for flat surface!

Comment: @RobinBetts, well... simply this finally: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/mSYOnYry/

Comment: @lemon Yay! This is actually quite handy stuff.. (e.g. landscapes, particles) [One quibble with your last](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/52mqMjq2/) :D

Answer (score 5):

**Copy Rotation Constraint.**

Possibly a simple way to do this is via a copy rotation constraint, to ensure the object faces the camera plane normal.

[image]

The camera looks down its -Z axis. For example sake if I put the number or some pattern on top of the default cube and make it copy the camera rotation.

(*Rotate your spheres in edit mode such that the number is aligned in top view.*)

[image]

*Note, to reiterate the cubes are not facing the camera, rather the opposite direction to the camera.  A track to constraint will target the camera directly*

Related

[Make an object Always face the camera, and always be upright?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183900/make-an-object-always-face-the-camera-and-always-be-upright)

[How to put rotation- and scale invariant labels to three dimensional objects (motion-tracked insert effect)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193980/how-to-put-rotation-and-scale-invariant-labels-to-three-dimensional-objects-mo)