# How do I map a texture along a vector going from multiple objects to the camera? Is it even possible?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, vector, vector-mapping

I'm trying to make a shader which has a procedural texture mapped along a vector between the camera view and the objects. Imagine the pink arrow as the vector in the picture below.

[image: The pink line is the vector I'm refering to]

I was able to make a shader with a similar effect (pictured below), however, the vector is parallel to the camera view rather than pointing toward it. Because of this, the shader doesn't create the desired result in perspective mode.
[image: Almost what I'm looking for]
(the gradient texture is just a placeholder)

My understanding of shaders is poor but I'll clarify my question as best I can if necessary.

Comment: Have a look at the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200352/35559) .. in particular @lemon's [last contribution](https://blend-exchange.com/b/mSYOnYry/) in the comments, which I wish had been a full answer.. :)

Comment: Don't we just need here to use "camera" output from the texture coordinates node?

Comment: @lemon ... the textures have to be independent, per-object? .. maybe Robert could clarify.

Comment: @RobinBetts That link gets me the vector I needed, although admittedly I can't wrap my head around the math required to get there. Thanks