# Map texture on Sphere so it always faces the view / camera

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, vector-mapping

Is there any way to project a 2d square texture on a sphere with some vector magic so it always fills the sphere and aligns with the camera? kinda like the window mapping option in the texture coordinate node.

i'm trying to create a 3d sphere with a billboarded texture so i can use it as a 3dimensional brushstroke.

the texture:

[image]

the texture projected on the sphere: (its supposed to look like this from any angle)

[image]

Comment: So why don't you use the Window or the Camera output of the Texture Coordinate?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap

Comment: Like a matcap https://youtu.be/4mlJKPactuo ?

Comment: Possibly relevant: especially @lemon s contributions in the commentary: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200352/35559

Comment: like a matcap, but actually visible in cycles render

Comment: @lemon s contribution works, thanks! the mapping still kinda slides back and fourth slightly but its mostly working

Comment: @Walter .. I'm taking it that you no longer need a distinct answer, so this question can be marked as a duplicate.. If !'m wrong. please go ahead and edit, explaining what more you need.